# How to make insert in three tables OOP PHP + MySql

Tags: php

My question is how to insert three tables that are related as follows:

Customer table :

```
id
name
Address
id_serie ( fk )
id_telefone ( fk )
```

Table Serie :

```
description
id_serie ( pk )
```

table Telephone

```
number
id_telefone ( pk )
```

I am using PHP and OOP + html + bootstrap

My code to insert:

```
if ($valid) {
    $pdo = Database::connect();
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO customers (name,address) values(?, ?, ?)";
    $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $q->execute(array($name,$email,$mobile));
    Database::disconnect();
    header("Location: index.php");
}
```

If the columns only belong to a table I know what to do, with relationships, I'm not getting it.

Comment: Check your column names in your insert statement '(name,address) values(?, ?, ?)'

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry, really has an error, the correct is: <$ sql = "INSERT INTO customers (name, address) values (?,?)";>
but it is possible to make the insert in the three tables at once? Because you need to insert the series and the telephone, that are in other tables. How should I proceed ?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you should first insert in series and telephone, then in customers. Something like that (if id_serie and id_telephone are autoincremented keys) :

```
if ($valid) {
    $pdo = Database::connect();
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $q = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO series (description) values(?)");
    $q->execute(array("Mobile");
    $serie = $q->lastInsertId();
    $q = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO telephone (number) values(?)");
    $q->execute(array($mobile);
    $tel = $q->lastInsertId();

    $sql = "INSERT INTO customers (name,address, id_serie, id_telefone) values(?, ?, ?, ?)";
    $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $q->execute(array($name,$email,$serie,$tel));
    Database::disconnect();
    header("Location: index.php");
}
```

You may also want to get an existing serie, then you have to make a fetch to get the correct id.

Comment: Yes it is this idea would be the same as a combo box , in inserting the user chooses the option ... but I can not do this ... do not know the name of the routine to be able to search ... a basic example would greatly help ...